# Regex starts with alphabet or underscore (_)

Tags: regex

I'm trying to check string starting with underscore(_) or alphabet and can contain only letters, digits, hyphens, underscores or periods.
The string can also be of length 1.

Expected valid strings:

1. _Name
2. _name.First
3. name-first
4. Name
5. name.First
6. name-first
7. A
8. b

I tried using the below given regex but is not working for a single alphabet.

`^[a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9_|/.|/-]{1,20}[a-zA-Z0-9]$`

Comment: `[\w-]` is probably almost but not quite what you want (effectively ± Unicode support)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_](?:[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{0,20}[a-zA-Z0-9])?$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/SeJLBW/3).

**Explanation**

```
                         EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-zA-Z0-9_]             any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z',
                           '0' to '9', '_'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z0-9_.-             any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to
    ]{0,20}                  'Z', '0' to '9', '_', '.', '-' (between
                             0 and 20 times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z0-9]              any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to
                             'Z', '0' to '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: It worked of almost every case. I came across where it correctly verify the starting string but in case of string with length 2 does not work. example:

1.  _Test.name - success  
2.  test_name - success  
3.  test-name - success  
4. _T - fail

Comment: @EngMyWorld Replace `{1,20}` with `{0,20}`.